# Two frames actions in the same div

Tags: javascript, html, frame

I have done that:

```
<body>      
  <div style="width:1170px; height:361px; border:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center;">
    <video id="video1" width="580" onclick="newDoc()" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()">          
      <source src="http://luxelumi.com/video/gio.mp4" type="video/mp4">          
      <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwICMK6VJoY" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video. 
    </video>
  </iframe>      
  <video id="video2" width="580" onclick="newDoc2()" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()">        
    <source src="http://luxelumi.com/video/luxelumi.mp4" type="video/mp4">        
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video. 
  </video>      
</div>    
<script>
  var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

  function playPause() {
      if (myVideo.paused) myVideo.play();
      else myVideo.pause();
  }

  function newDoc() {
      window.location.assign("http://www.google.it")
  }
  var myVideo = document.getElementById("video2");

  function playPause() {
      if (myVideo.paused) myVideo.play();
      else myVideo.pause();
  }

  function newDoc2() {
      window.location.assign("http://luxelumi.com/luxelumi.html")
  }
</script>
</body>
```

It works perfectly.
But I want that the 2 functions `newDoc()`,`newDoc2()` to open the 2 URL in the same div of the videos, like a frame, how to achieve that?

thanks

Comment: It's a little bit hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you please attach some mockups/screenshots, or something?

Answer (score 0):

Use `iframe` elements to load a pages within, say, a `div`.

Comment: I know how use an iframe. but how use here?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I know how use an iframe. but how use it here?

example: there are 2 videos (videoA-videoB) and one div(DivA) and 2 pages that must open in the same container (pageA, PageB)

1. onclick VideoA open pageA and stay in divA
2. onclick VideoB open pageB and stay in divA